# Implement Rabbit MQ - (Aysnchronous) RPC with Spring Boot

Tags: asynchronous, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp

In RabbitMQ official website, they suggest to create a single callback queue per client to implement RPC pattern.
The code snippet for client(producer) looks like below:

```
public RPCClient() throws Exception {
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
connection = factory.newConnection();
channel = connection.createChannel();

replyQueueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue(); 
consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
channel.basicConsume(replyQueueName, true, consumer);
```

But I can't find any article on the web to implement this by Spring Boot - AMQP, all the examples just send and receive sequentially (or say synchronously).

I wonder know how to achieve asynchronous message communication with just one request queue and reply queue.

p.s. I also tried `AsyncRabbitTemplete` but it didn't work.